# Link-only answer where the link is to another post on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I ran into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251079/what-is-the-get-eval-equivalent-for-selenium-webdriver-in-python/6514434#6514434) in a review queue - it's a link-only answer where the link is to another answer on Stack Overflow - so there was some question as to whether this fits the "link only answer" flag.  (I have no idea why a four year old answer was in the review queue - based on the number of questions/answers I saw in the queue that were from this user I'd say that he (she?) pissed somebody off, but whatever.)

In this situation, is the correct review action for a *recent* answer of this type (as opposed to a four year old answer):

1. Flag as link-only
2. Do nothing, because the link is to Stack Overflow and therefore is relatively durable
3. Flag the question as a duplicate
4. Fourth option